# What do the dip test output parameters mean?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, computational-statistics, mode

This may sound like a silly question, but I'm not a statistician, mathematician, or programmer, really. I did quite a bit of googling, including looking into Stack Exchange, but couldn't find a clear answer.

I have three plots and do the corresponding dip tests in R.

[image]

```
> dip.test(x$V1, simulate.p.value = FALSE, B = 2000)
```

Hartigans' dip test for unimodality

data:  x$V1
D = 0.0035, p-value = 0.9142 alternative hypothesis: non-unimodal, i.e., at least bimodal

[image]

```
> dip.test(x$V4, simulate.p.value = FALSE, B = 2000)

Hartigans' dip test for unimodality
```

data:  x$V4
D = 0.0046, p-value = 0.4947
alternative hypothesis: non-unimodal, i.e., at least bimodal

[image]

```
> dip.test(x$V6, simulate.p.value = FALSE, B = 2000)

Hartigans' dip test for unimodality
```

data:  x$V6
D = 0.0043, p-value = 0.6293
alternative hypothesis: non-unimodal, i.e., at least bimodal

What do D and P mean? The density distribution of V6 (last image) looks the "most" bimodal of all, but has intermediate D and P values. I have to write a script and have to test for bimodality. How would you advise me to discern between bimodal and unimodal distributions?

Comment: I came across a few methods for cluster analysis with R. Is there a function to which you give your numerical data and it gives you back the number of clusters - an integer?

Comment: If you have a new question about cluster analysis, you should ask a new question rather than try to ask new questions in comments.

Comment: Which R package are you running? `diptest`?

Comment: Yes. I threw this snippet of code in my question to make that clear:


> dip.test(x$V6, simulate.p.value = FALSE, B = 2000)

Comment: No, that doesn't make it clear - it only makes it clear that the name of the function you called is `dip.test`. Any number of packages could have a function called `dip.test`. To make it clear which package the function is from, you might show `library(diptest)`.

Comment: $D$ is defined in the original paper by Hartigan and Hartigan, [here](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176346577). The definition of a p-value is *the probability of a test statistic at least as extreme as the one obtained in the sample, given the null hypothesis is true*.

Comment: Ooops, sorry. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18307/discussion-between-user3790338-and-glen-b).

Comment: In simple terms, is there a critical D/P value above/below which the distribution is unimodal. I was thinking in terms of critical values, as in the Mann-Whitney test, for example. Below 0.05 (or whatever you fancy) - significant, otherwise - insignificant.

Comment: I had wanted to point you to the first sentence [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) but it was recently changed to be both confusing and wrong so I didn't... but now it seems to be restored to its former correctness, so take a look there as well.